# How to make an if/else statement loop?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm new to Javascript, so I'm not sure if I'm asking the right question here. But I have 6 elements - 6 trees, that a user can click on and then they disappear. After all of them have disappeared, I want something else to happen. But since I don't know what order the user will click them in (and I haven't really learned that much about JS yet) I thought that an if/else statement asking if there's only 0 trees left, then call a new function.

Unfortunately I cannot seem to get it to work, I don't know if I'm writing it the wrong way or placing it the wrong place or just doing it wrong, but it seems like it gives a false result already in the beginning, since the user hasn't clicked on anything yet. So how do I make it run in a loop and check how many trees are left several times?

Sorry the code is a bit long, but I'm not really sure how to optimise it and make it shorter just yet.

```
var TreesLeft = 6;
function TreeGoneOnClick(){
console.log("TreeGoneOnClick");
    BigTrees.classList.add("flash");
//click each tree
    tree1.addEventListener("click", tree1Clicked);
    tree2.addEventListener("click", tree2Clicked);
    tree3.addEventListener("click", tree3Clicked);
    tree4.addEventListener("click", tree4Clicked);
    tree5.addEventListener("click", tree5Clicked);
    tree6.addEventListener("click", tree6Clicked);

ifelse();
}

function tree1Clicked (){
    console.log("tree1 clicked");
    TreesLeft-=1;
    tree1.classList.remove("tree1S");
}

function tree2Clicked (){
    console.log("tree2 clicked");
    TreesLeft-=1;
    tree2.classList.remove("tree2S");
}

function tree3Clicked (){
    console.log("tree3 clicked");
    TreesLeft-=1;
    tree3.classList.remove("tree3S");
}

function tree4Clicked (){
    console.log("tree4 clicked");
    TreesLeft=TreesLeft-1;
    tree4.classList.remove("tree4S");
}

function tree5Clicked (){
    console.log("tree5 clicked");
    TreesLeft-=1;
    tree5.classList.remove("tree5S");
}

function tree6Clicked (){
    console.log("tree6 clicked");
    TreesLeft-=1;
    tree6.classList.remove("tree6S");
}



function ifelse(){
    if (TreesLeft ==0){
    console.log("it worked");
     allTreesGone();
     }
    else {
    console.log("did not work");
    }
  }


 function allTreesGone (){
   console.log("All trees are gone");
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can call your `ifelse()` function at the end of every `treeXClicked` function instead of at the end of your `TreeGoneOnClick` function.

Answer (score 1):

Call the ifElse function fron the event listeners instaed of calling it once on the TreesGoneOnClick function.

I assume the this method is called once and before any clickings were made,  since this is where you register your event listeners. 
The test of how many trees were left should be made after every click,  and therefore in the listeners

Answer (score 0):

It gets simpler if you consolidate the callbacks and check for your condition all in one code block.

```
function treeClicked(num, evt) {
    //evt.target contains a reference to the tree clicked
    //so you don't really need num, but just in case
    console.log("tree" + num + " clicked");
    treesLeft -= 1;
    if (treesLeft <= 0)
        callSomeOtherFunction();
}
```

If you really need to know the index of the tree that's clicked (i.e. `evt` is not sufficient), you can achieve that with bind:

```
//set the callback value of num and the this reference
//so when this tree is clicked num will equal 1
tree1.addEventListener("click", treeClicked.bind(this, 1));
```